# Maintaining Grouping When Exporting to Excel from SQL

Tags: sql-server, export-to-excel

I have a query that provides the results I want but when I export to excel, it does not maintain the grouping that I want.  Query is something like this.

```
SELECT
CASE
  WHEN A.LOC = 'M09' THEN 'BIN'
  WHEN A.LOC = 'M08' THEN 'BULK'
  ELSE A.LOC
  END AS WORK_ZONE,
A.CY_NO, SUM(A.PICK)

FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE A.CY_NO IN ('01', '02', '03')

GROUP BY 
CASE
  WHEN A.LOC = 'M09' THEN 'BIN'
  WHEN A.LOC = 'M08' THEN 'BULK'
  ELSE A.LOC
  END,
A.CY_NO,
SUM(A.PICK)
```

This is SQL thru QMF Version 10 and when I run the query it produces the results I want.  But when I export to Excel,Instead of 1 Field for M09 with a sum, it gives all the rows where loc = M09.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: We would need to see your `WHERE` clause which you did not include here.

Comment: I'm sorry.  The Where clause would be  Where A.CY_NO IN ('01', '02', '03',))

Answer (score 0):

[image: Excel External Data Properties]

Right click on the resulting table in Excel, navigate to Table -- External Data Properties, and uncheck the "Preserve column sort/filter/layout" option. When you refresh your table it should populate the way your SQL query intended it to.

Comment: Hi Usrey, any luck with this?

Comment: No the properties prompt was not lit up for me to access.